# what does "recommending itself" mean?

Tags: meaning

The sentence is as follow: "... this view of things, recommending itself equally to the intelligence of thinkers and to the inclination of those important classes ..." 
In this sentence, what does "recommending itself" means? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from *On Liberty* by John Stuart Mill:

> The limitation, therefore, of the power of government over individuals
>   loses none of its importance when the holders of power are regularly
>   accountable to the community, that is, to the strongest party therein.
>   **This view of things, recommending itself equally to the intelligence of thinkers and to the inclination of those important classes** in
>   European society to whose real or supposed interests democracy is
>   adverse, has had no difficulty in establishing itself;

The "view of things" is the necessity of limiting the power of a democratic government so that the majority cannot abuse the minority.  "Recommending itself equally" means that this view is equally attractive to two groups -- those who think about political philosophy (the "thinkers") and those whose propertied interests might suffer at the hands of the more numerous and less endowed (the "important classes").